# Set z-index of OverlayView in react-google-maps

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I am using [react-google-maps](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps) and I want to accomplish something similar to Airbnb where when you hover over a search result and then a "marker" (aka `OverlayView`) is highlighted on the map. But the issue I am trying to solve is if an `OverlayView` is underneath another `OverlayView`, I want to bring that "active" `OverlayView` to the top (like by adjusting the z-index). The map on Airbnb does this very thing, which is when you hover over the search result and inspect the marker the `z-index` is altered to be `9001` to ensure it is brought to the front of all other markers.

There are a few issues related to this from years ago that have not received any movement:

[tomchentw/react-google-maps#199](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/199)
[tomchentw/react-google-maps#93](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/93)

In issue #199 it was mentioned you could hack around it with `this.refs.childDiv.parentNode` and setting `z-index` on that, but in React v16 `this.refs` is no longer a thing from what I can tell (it was deprecated). The original commenter attached a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/medmunds/9b7qr7v8/) with the code sample which was:

```
class OverlayViewExample extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const pos = {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644};
    const mapPane = OverlayView.OVERLAY_MOUSE_TARGET;
    const getOffset = this.getPixelPositionOffset.bind(this);

    return (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={8}
        defaultCenter={pos}
      >
        <OverlayView
          position={pos}
          mapPaneName={mapPane}
          getPixelPositionOffset={getOffset}
        >
          <div style={{zIndex: 2}} className="overlay" ref="childDiv">This should be in front</div>
        </OverlayView>

        <OverlayView
          position={pos}
          mapPaneName={mapPane}
          getPixelPositionOffset={getOffset}
        >
          <div style={{zIndex: 1}} className="overlay">Another overlay should be in front of me</div>
        </OverlayView>
      </GoogleMap>
    );
  }

  getPixelPositionOffset (width, height) {
    // this.refs is an empty object when I tried this :(
    if (this.refs.childDiv) {
        this.refs.childDiv.parentNode.style.zIndex = 2;
    }
    return { x: -(width / 2), y: -(height / 2) };
  }
}
```

When I tried this workaround, `this.refs` was an empty object and therefore I could not alter the underlying `zIndex` of that node.

Is there another way to ensure when two `OverlayView`s are near each other that I can bring the one in the background to the foreground?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer for this was actually in my question (I should've tested the example code from Github)...

On this line: `<div style={{zIndex: 2}} className="overlay" ref="childDiv">This should be in front</div>` the `zIndex` was actually doing what I wanted (it would bring forward whichever element I wanted in the foreground).

So within each `OverlayView`, just apply a `z-index` to the first child element and that will effect the ordering of each `OverlayView`.